# Placing Particles along the median line of a letter

Tags: particles, bezier-curves

I'm supposed to place a bunch of lights along the median path of a letter.

What I mean by "median path" is if you were able to negatively offset a letter so much, till it becomes just a line describing the letter in question.

In other words, what I call the median path of a letter should look like what someone would write on a paper. A letter written with a simple line. In the picture below, in red.

The text is a regular blender text (curve) generated through python so I can't place the particles by hand. It needs to be dynamic so I have to do it with python. Of course, I can convert the curve into a mesh if that helps...

[image: Letter blue, path read, particles white]

My question is:

How do I get the median path of all letters in that text and how do I place particles at non-random intervals along that path?

Any help is appreciated. If you don't know python, it's ok, I can figure out that part later.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. You are welcome to ask as many separate questions as you need.

Comment: Also how is this letter generated? Is it a Mesh object? Is it a bezier curve? Is an actual text? What is it's topology like? Do you already have this "median path"?

Comment: Am I right that you want to recreate the old ad signs on roof tops, something like that?

Comment: That's exactly it!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos
The text is just a regular curve text object into which the content is injected by script. No, I don't have this path. I need to calculate it depending on each letter. I don't have the size, the font nor the content either. It's set through script. 
It's basically an automatic sign simulator. (...for signs like the kind you find on top of a shop)

Comment: The thing is this is not at all trivial to calculate. I mean first and foremost it is largely font dependent, each font would have a different "median path" for the same character. Most characters again depending on the font may have variable width, so if you just offset from the borders, this will yeild either an area, or a self intersecting solution. You also can't just guaratee the creation of this path, most fonts have a relatively regular shape, but there may be bulges, serifs, rough outlines and all sorts of irregularities that make it non trivial to relate two opposing borders.

Comment: One workaround might just be to manually create your set of characters pre assembled with their own path and light setup, then use said collection of [objects as a font](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/texts/properties.html#objects-as-fonts)